# ffmpeg video compression : Compress captured video being before saving to file

Tags: ffmpeg, compression

Is there a way one can compress captured video input before saving to file? I have raspberry pi that I am using to record youtube videos. 1-2 min video takes over a Gb of space. I cant compress the recorded file because the pi does not have enough space to record the initial video. Is there a way using ffmpeg I can compress my webcam video directly after its captured before saving the file versus waiting until I am done recording then compressing the saved file?

I'm using

`ffmpeg \ -f v4l2 \ -thread_queue_size 5000 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -y -c:v libx264 ~/Desktop/ffmpegTesting/money.mp4 \ -thread_queue_size 5000 -f alsa -ac 1 -ar 44100 -i hw:1,0 -t 30 -c:v copy -c:a ~/Desktop/ffmpegTesting/money.mp4 \`

Comment: Ive managed to compress before saving but the audio is disapearring now :(

Comment: to be more exact. The audio disappears around the 10-11 second mark in the video

Comment: Syntax is malformed, it should be: `ffmpeg -f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 5000 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -thread_queue_size 5000 -f alsa -i hw:1,0 -c:v libx264 -ac 1 -ar 44100 -c:a aac -y ~/Desktop/ffmpegTesting/money.mp4`

Comment: The error I am getting now is :  cannot set channel count to 2 (Invalid argument)
hw:1,0: Input/output error

Comment: Ok i fixed problem by setting hw:1,0 to plughw:1,0

Comment: ffmpeg -f v4l2 -thread_queue_size 5000 -framerate 25 -video_size 640x480 -i /dev/video0 -thread_queue_size 5000 -f alsa -i plughw:1,0 -c:v libx264 -ac 2 -ar 44100 -c:a aac -y ~/Desktop/ffmpegTesting/money.mp4

Comment: The audio still times out before the video ends

Comment: After further testing it appears the audio always times out a 4 - 5 seconds before the video ends no matter the length of video. Im starting to belive it has somehting to do when I stop the process. Maybe there is a lag between the video being compressed and adding the audio to it.

Comment: How are you ending the process?

Comment: Either by pressing Q or Ctrl C